# Create an attribute for an inherited property

Tags: delphi, inheritance, attributes, delphi-2010

[EDITED] I'm trying to get RTTI to recognise the "Items" property of the TList generic class so that I can apply an attribute to it. I've written a console app which outputs the RTTI properties here:

```
program RTTIAttributes;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  Generics.Collections,
  RTTI,
  SysUtils;

type

  TDataMember = class(TCustomAttribute);

  TCustomer = class
  private
    FName: string;
  public
    [TDataMember]
    property Name: string read FName write FName;  // <- attribute IS recognised by RTTI
  end;

  { inheritance tree: TList<T> -> TObjectList<T> -> TCustomerList
  Here are the base properties declared in TList<T>
  TList<T> = class(TEnumerable<T>)
  ...
  public
    property Capacity: Integer read GetCapacity write SetCapacity;
    property Count: Integer read FCount write SetCount;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: T read GetItem write SetItem; default;   <- not recognised as RTTI property...!
    property OnNotify: TCollectionNotifyEvent<T> read FOnNotify write FOnNotify;
  end;
  }

  TCustomerList = class(TObjectList<TCustomer>)
  public
    //[TDataMember]
    property Items;  // <- inherited property, but NOT recognised by RTTI & hence cannot inspect attributes
  end;

procedure DoRTTIObject(AObject: TObject);
var
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  LProp: TRttiProperty;
  LAttr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  LContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    Writeln('Process Class: ' + AObject.ClassName);
    for LProp in LContext.GetType(AObject.ClassType).GetProperties do
    begin
      Writeln('Found Property: ' + AObject.ClassName + '.' + LProp.Name);
      for LAttr in LProp.GetAttributes do
        if LAttr is TDataMember then
          Writeln(AObject.ClassName + '.' + LProp.Name + ': HAS TDataMember attribute')
        else
          Writeln(AObject.ClassName + '.' + LProp.Name + ': DOES NOT HAVE TDataMember attribute');
    end;
    Writeln('');
  finally
    LContext.Free;
  end;
end;

var
  LList: TCustomerList;
begin

  LList := TCustomerList.Create;
  LList.Add(TCustomer.Create);
  DoRTTIObject(LList);
  DoRTTIObject(LList[0]);

  Readln;
end.
```

The above console app produces the following output:

```
Process Class: TCustomerList
Found Property: TCustomerList.OwnsObjects
Found Property: TCustomerList.Capacity
Found Property: TCustomerList.Count
Found Property: TCustomerList.OnNotify

Process Class: TCustomer
Found Property: TCustomer.Name
TCustomer.Name: HAS TDataMember attribute
```

So for whatever reason that I can't determine, RTTI recognises 3 but not 4 of the declared properties of the ancestor class.

Any ideas?

Comment: What delphi version? Changing visibility from protected to public may not be enough. Perhaps you should be promoting it to published and using classic (not extended) RTTI.

Comment: Delphi 2010. The inherited property (Items) was already public in the ancestor class. I'm simply trying to re-declare it and introduce an attribute. Setting it to published did not work, it gives the error: E2188 Published property 'Items' cannot be of type ARRAY. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Oh it's an array type and you want to use extended RTTI on it?  I suggest you get rid of the array-of-x and use a Collection.  If you are not familiar with `TCollectionItem` that's the classic-rtti way to embed a flexible number of objects and provide classic standard RTTI for it. As it would then be of a class type, attributes would work.

Comment: I'm descending from TObjectList<> so I think that uses TEnumerable. I don't want to change the base type of Items, I just want to be able to add an attribute to the property which I can detect using RTTI.

Comment: I think that the omission of all this information makes your question hard to answer. Perhaps a minimal complete example of a type exhibiting this issue would be good to post instead of the untyped code above.  The fact that TCustomerList is a TObjectList is irrelevant to the property Items, what is its type?

Comment: Thanks Warren, I've updated the question & provided a fully compiled example. Any further comments would be appreciated

Comment: Any ideas ?? Bueller? Bueller?

Comment: Much better question now. +1